# Can not connect to my remote apps only remote desktop with same IP

Tags: azure, rdp, windows-server-2019

I have set up an server on Azure and have the Remote Desktop service running with a couple apps I want to connect with.

I can see my apps but when trying to connect I get

> We couldn't connect to the remote PC because the PC can't be found. Please provide the fully-qualified name or the IP address of the remote PC, and then try again.
>
> Error code: 0x104

Workspace with apps showing

[image]

I have no problem connecting to same server with Remote Desktop, but only the apps. When connecting to the RDP I use the public IP and port so I think there might be and issue in Azure not letting me in?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot connect to the remote Azure VM? Do you check the NSG rule for the RDP port?

Comment: I can connect to the Azure remote VM but not the apps, I can see them as resource but get the error above. I would think all should be fine since I can connect to Remote Desktop, but it will not let me connect to the apps.

Comment: Do you add the NSG rules to allow access for the port you need to use?

Comment: Hi, NSG rules should be good.

Comment: Do you check if your application run well inside the VM?

Comment: ITs paint and runs fine when connected to the VM